# Как сделать так, чтобы экземпляр конструктора возвращал примитивный тип?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Есть конструктор. Нужно, чтобы экземпляр от него возвращал инкремент.
Как это можно и лучше реализовать?

```
'use strict'

function Count() {

  // Здесь правильный код

}

var newCount = new Count();

alert(newCount); // 1 

alert(newCount); // 2 

alert(newCount + newCount); // 7
```

Comment: никак :-) конструктор не может возвращать _примитивные_ типы

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Конструктор *не может* возвращать *примитивные* типы. Поэтому формально ответ на вопрос: никак.

Но можно воспользоваться возможностью определения для объектов функций [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) и [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf), которые вызываются автоматически при приведениях к различным типам, например:

```js
function Count() {

  var val = 0;
  this.valueOf = this.toString = function() {
    return ++val;
  };

}

var newCount = new Count();
document.write(newCount); // 1 
document.write(newCount); // 2 
document.write(newCount + newCount); // 7
```